# any link to a tested and working source code for other content defined chunking algorithms below : Rabin, TTTD, AE, LMC

Tags: duplicates, rabin-karp, text-chunking

I want a free source code for lab tests on the algorithms listed

Rabin
AE
LMC
TTTD

Anyone or any application running on these algorithms would be appreciated

I found Restic version of Rabin CDC on Github but the application does not reveal the number of chunks.
Currently searching for free algorithms on Content defined chunking for research purposes